# How to implement an adaptive information filter of a CSR sparse matrix representing an article and integers 0-4 representing the topic of the article?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, python-class, recommendation-engine

I have the following tuple stored in a variable called newsfeed, which contains a row vector in the form of a CSR sparse matrix of shape (1, 9635) representing a news article and an integer from 0-4 (inclusive) representing the topic of the news article, where:

```
{0: "business", 1: "entertainment", 2: "politics", 3: "sport", 4: "tech"}
```

Example of the top 10 newsfeed tuple:

```
Index: 0 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 122 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 0)
Index: 1 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 176 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 0)
Index: 2 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 136 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 2)
Index: 3 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 65 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 2)
Index: 4 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 159 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 2)
Index: 5 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 106 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 1)
Index: 6 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 98 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 0)
Index: 7 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 106 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 0)
Index: 8 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 271 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 3)
Index: 9 (<1x9635 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 143 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, 0)
```

I need to build an Adaptive Information Filter (AIF) class that uses its classifier self.clf to select news articles of interest and the corresponding topics, and yield them as a tuple (e.g., yield news_vecs, topics, where news_vecs is a 2D CSR sparse matrix of shape (N, 9635) and topics is an np.ndarray of shape (N,). And N is dynamically determined by the classifier.)

This is what I have so far my AIF class skeleton:

```
import scipy.sparse
import numpy as np

class AIF:
    
    def __init__(self, random_state=None):
        
        self.clf = None # Any classifier of my choice
        self.random_state = 42 # in case you need one

    def filtering(self, newsfeed, batch_sz=100):

        # Some additional variables may be needed
        # Step into the newsfeed
        for idx, (news_vec, topic) in enumerate(newsfeed):
            # Yield news_vecs and topics when a full batch has arrived
        # For simplicity, you can ignore any incomplete batches after the newsfeed is exhausted

    def gather_feedback(self, feedback, news_vecs, topics):
        
        # feedback may be a degenerate np.ndarray if news_vecs and topics are degenerate
        
        return # Feedback
```

Comment: So which part are you stuck on ?

Comment: stuck on yielding news_vecs and topics when a full batch arrives